# Why do I have to first pull an image before I can get the docker rest api returns something?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-repository

I want to use the docker rest api specifically 
`http://{url}/images/{image}/json`

I'm running the same API on different machines, but why it shows different results?

Is there a way to get all the images list on a repository without first pulling the images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The docker api only shows images on a specific docker host. For images on a remote registry, you'd need to use the registry api.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/